# Compilation of a code: unknown type name string

Tags: c, arrays, string, compilation

I have the following lines of code but the compiler says the following: "unknown type name 'string'" both in the declaration and definition of the function. What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fRecognizeClient(string *ActualClient)
```

Comment: There's no such type as 'string' in C

Comment: There is no type named `string` in the standard library. If you want to pass a single string to your function, it needs a parameter of type `char*` (which can point to a string).

Comment: There is indeed no such type in C. Try `char*` instead of that `string*`.

Comment: please read error message and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no string type in c. You need to use an array like so:

```
char array[10];
```

Then you can pass it in to your function:

```
void fRecognizeClient(char *ActualClient);
```

Comment: Or, in formal arguments, a `char*` since in function calls array arguments are *decayed* to pointers.

Comment: you can't pass array in C

Comment: You can have an array actual argument, but that is understood as a pointer, e.g. `char buf[10]; snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", (int)getpid());` the first `buf` actual argument to `snprintf` *is* an array *decayed* to a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

In C++, there is no type "string". Try to use container class std::string with
`<string>` header.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. But there is no such type in C too.